# Is there any advantage in having the nav tabs and tab panes in the same div?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, tabpanel

In the documentation for [Toggable Tabs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs) for bootstrap version 3, the nav tabs and the tab panes are within the same div. Is there any advantage to this?

```
<div>

  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="settings">...</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

compared to just having

```
<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">...</div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">...</div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">...</div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="settings">...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its generally best to group up content but seeming as that div doesn't have a class added onto it it really doesn't matter.